# Flask Python - Adding links to other websites from a list of URLs

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a web app and store links to other sites in my MongoDB database using flask. I can now store the links, also display them but instead of directing me to that site keeps me flask app. This is what I've done

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<center>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Enter URL">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter name">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-danger">
    </form>
    {% for item in data %}
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <h3 class="card-title">{{ item['name'] }}</h3>
        <a href="{{ item['link'] }}" class="btn btn-danger">Link</a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</center>
{% endblock %}
```

Let's say I want to go to https://example.com, it takes me to http://127.0.0.1:5000/https://example.com instead. I can provide more code if needed, just thought this should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a route for this in flask:

```
@app.route('/go_outside_flask')
def go_outside_flask_method():
    return redirect("http://www.example.com", code=302)
```

And then in the `item['link']` you can store `go_outside_flask` or you can simply have `{{ url_for('go_outside_flask_method') }}`.

**Note**: if you have many such redirects, it will be difficult to maintain all these routes.

Another approach would be to build a dynamic URL:

```
@app.route('go_outside_flask/<variable>')
def go_outside_flask_method(variable):
    redirect(variable, code=302)
```

You can call this like:

```
<a href = {{ url_for('go_outside_flask', varible=item['link']) }}>Link</a>
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Come to think of it that is a good idea. But what I was trying to do was get the urls from a mongodb database. I used a for loop to loop through the urls. This method would basically mean hard-coding them, when I actually am storing these urls from user in my database. Is there some other way? I can think of using this method, but like you said having too many would be a problem.